# Objective function condition on variable comparison

Tags: linear-regression, cvxpy, piecewise

I am wondering whether cvxpy can handle objective function depending on the variable comparison. To be more specific:

```
import cvxpy as cp
p1=cp.Variable()
p2=cp.Variable()
p3=cp.Variable()
p4=cp.Variable()
v0=cp.Variable()
v1=cp.Variable()

v = ... # v is a linear combination of other variables
if v <= v0:
    objective = p1 + p2*v
else if v>=v0 and v<=v1:
    objective = v
else:
    objective = p3 + p4*v
p = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize((objective-y**2)) # y is the observations I want to fit against
```

Is there a generic way to do it?

Comment: The only way is to have a mixed-integer model of your piecewise linear function. For instance like here https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#continuous-piecewise-linear-functions

Comment: Thanks. I read through it, but not sure I completely understand it. Could you please elaborate? I edited my question so it reflects more of what I need. px, vx are all variables that I need to optimise.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I can add to that text. You cannot define your model on the level of ``if-else`` in Python, you have to create a model that will be understandable to the optimizer and that requires MIP modeling in this case. If you want to understand the idea then look at the easier models earlier in that section, such as 9.1.1. You can also find yourself an optimizer that directly accepts PWL functions in its API and use that instead of CVXPY.